# PHP - MySQL how to show only supplier_name in select but the next page i can get the supplier_id?

Tags: php, mysql

i have use explode, but it won't works.
this is my code.

```
$sup="SELECT supplier_id,supplier_name FROM tblSupplier";
    $s=mysql_query($sup);
   <?php


while($suppl=mysql_fetch_array($s)){
            ?><option value=<?echo $suppl[0].'_'.$suppl[1]?> selected> <?php echo $suppl[1];?></option>
            <?php } ?></select></td>  

$supplier = explode("_", $_POST['supplier_name']);
$supplier_id = $supplier['0'];
$supplier_name = $supplier['1'];
```

another problem is i need looping because i want to input 10 inputs in one page.

Thanks in advance for the time and efforts for helping me...

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: @Charles did you mean in future versions of PHP we cannot use mysql_* functions at all??

Comment: @softgenic, *years from now*, the `mysql_` family of functions is being retired, yes.  It may still be available as a PECL extension, but it won't be bundled with PHP any longer.  The soonest this could happen is the next release *after* 5.5, which isn't even in beta yet.  While old code will continue to work for quite a while, any new code you write should only use modern, supported database libraries.  *This has been the case since **2004**, when mysqli was bundled with PHP 5.0.0.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the explode code before your use the loop, try this instead:

```
<?php
   $sup="SELECT supplier_id,supplier_name FROM tblSupplier";
   $s=mysql_query($sup);
   if (!$s) { echo 'Sorry, there was an error!'; }
   $supplier = explode("_", $_POST['supplier_name']);
   $supplier_id = $supplier[0];
   $supplier_name = $supplier[1]; # you don't need this
   echo '<select name="supplier_name">';
   while ($suppl = mysql_fetch_array($s)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$suppl[0].'_'.$suppl[1].'"';
        if ($suppl[0] == $supplier_id) {
             echo 'selected';
        }
        echo '>'.$suppl[1].'</option>';
   echo '</select>';
?>
```